# How to detect message threads using JavaMail on Android?

Tags: java, android, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I'm writing an email client for Android using the [javamail-android](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) library. I would like to detect Gmail threads to be able to display all messages from one thread together. I'd rather not download all messages in the inbox folder though. What I want is to display only recent messages/threads. How can I do it and do I have to use external libraries for this?

I managed to find [java-gmail-imap](https://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/) which seems to be doing what I want. Does anyone have any experience with it and/or can suggest possible alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, you can use my port [here](https://github.com/ruiaraujo/javamail_android). I have used it for a project successfully, I just replaced the java dependencies with Harmony implementations and turn it in a Android library project to make sure one is not using anything that isn't supported. You can make a jar out of it (which I should :P ).

Comment: Before you answered my question I basically did the same thing. I took the original JavaMail code and added necessary dependencies from javamail-android. I had to make some slight changes in the code and get around the mailcap file problem that you describe, but I managed to get it working. I like the idea of creating an Android dependency project. I might switch to your solution after all.

Answer (score 0):

The latest JavaMail release includes support for all the Gmail IMAP protocol extensions, including the ThreadID, but I have no idea if it works on Android, which isn't real Java.

Comment: Original JavaMail doesn't work on Android. javamail-android is based on an old JavaMail version (1.4.1) and does not support the new Gmail extensions.

Comment: Yup, what a shame that Android isn't Java.